# Infinite Sums in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if there is a way to do infinite sums in Excel. I have a sum in the form

= $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)g(n) $$

I was wondering if there is a function to do this in Excel as I dont really want to do a finite sum to a very large number in order to approximate the infinite sum.

Comment: I was unable in this forum to get mathjax

Comment: You might be able to do an infinite sum, but it would take a long, long time to calculate

Comment: The closest thing to **infinite** in an [excel-formula] is the `#DIV/0!` error and that halts processing for the same reason @Gary'sStudent has mentioned. [edit] fwiw, the largest possible positive number is 9.99999999999999E+307, the largest possible negative number is -9.99999999999999E+307. [source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel isn't a computer algebra system, so it can't do things like sum infinite series symbolically. The following VBA function might help:

```
Function PartialSum(f As String, var As String, start As Long, finish As Long) As Double
    Dim i As Long, sum As Double
    Dim term As String

    For i = start To finish
        term = Replace(f, var, "(" & i & ")")
        sum = sum + Evaluate(term)
    Next I

    PartialSum = sum
End Function
```

Then, for example, if you put `=PartialSum("1/n","n",1,1000)` in a worksheet cell it evaluates to `1.643934567`. Caution must be taken that you don't use things like `sin(n)` in the terms since the function just does simple text substitutions and would hence try to evaluate things like `"si(1)((1))"` in that particular case. The obvious workaround would be to choose as a variable some symbol that does not otherwise occur in the expression.